# Powershell - Batch Rename of Home Server in HomePath

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Admittedly, I am not a PowerShell monster, so I'm going to punt...

I am working with a client who is pulling a list of all his user shares on his CIFS server to help redirect AD HomeDirectory paths in a major file server migration.  This list is being compared to the list of AD users home directories as AD currently sees them.

The problem is that some user directories use old NT Usernames (**NAMEI$**) and some use **SAMAACCOUNTNAME$**.  To Additionally complicate, the share **SERVER** differs in AD due to an elaborate history of DNS aliases over the past 10-15 years - so even though all the users home directories currently exist on **SERVERA** they could be mapped to **OLDSERVER3**, **OLDERSERVER01**, or **OLDESTSERVERNT4** - resulting in home directories that are all over the map.

I need to write a script that can use the **SAMACCOUNTNAME** from a list, then change all the server information in the home directory to **\NEWSEVERNAME\CURRENTSHARE$** - hopefully using something like this:

```
Use UserList
From UserList, get-ADuser -Identity $_ -HomeDrive "U:" -HomeDirectory
in HomeDirectory replace \\*\ with \\NewServer\ while leaving the Share$ untouched.
Set-ADuser -Identity $_ -HomeDrive "U:" -HomeDirectory
```

I'm fairly certain that this can be accomplished with regular expressions, for/each loops, etc... but I can't put it together.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can use .split() to extract the sharename. this should do the trick: `$homedir = (Get-ADUser $user -Properties homedirectory).homedirectory; $tmp = $homedir.split("\"); $share = $tmp[$tmp.count-1]; set-aduser $user -homedirectory "$newserver\$share"`

Comment: Got it figured out - thanks for your help on this, Paul!

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same migration a short while ago.  Here is what you can use to set the new server while leaving the share folder untouched.

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$samAccountNameList = get-content "c:\userIds.txt"
$newServer = "newFps01"

foreach ($user in $samAccountNameList) {
    $adProperties = get-aduser -Identity $user -Properties homeDirectory, homeDrive
    $homeDrive = $adProperties.HomeDrive
    # Split original homedirectory path and grab just the share folder portion
    $shareFolder = ($adProperties.homeDirectory).Split("\")[3]
    $newHomeDirectory = "\\$newServer\$shareFolder"
    set-aduser -Identity $user -HomeDrive $homeDrive -HomeDirectory $newHomeDirectory
}
```